# how to publish a wordpress website in hostinger?

Tags: wordpress, hosting

I have migrated a website from wordpress.com(export xml) to hostinger. The website now pointing a domain created in hostinger.My question is that when I run this website in browser it shows blank page.Any help regarding this issue shall be appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen this guide yet? [Moving to Self-Hosted WordPress](https://move.wordpress.com/)